# How to change an image when drop-down is changed?

Tags: javascript

I am just not learning JS and I have a couple of images and would like to change them when my select is changed

here is code:

```
<select id="Class" name="Class" onchange="CharacterClass(this)">
        <option value="Fighter">Fighter</option>
        <option value="Ranger">Ranger</option>
        <option value="Rouge">Rouge</option>
```

Comment: where is the image? are you using jquery or plain javascript? what is this `CharacterClass`? what you have tried..?

Comment: Sidenote: you should probably make that "Rogue", or I'm not sure how interested people would be in playing that particular class.

Comment: Have you tried some javascript for it?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example you can adapt to your situation.

```js
function CharacterClass(selector){
  let image = document.getElementById("ClassImage");
  if(selector.value === "Hat") {
      image.src = "https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.IeoYLek51JlXIt92tyhXvQHaFF&pid=Api&rs=1"
  } else {
      image.src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f0/Shoe-Blucher-Black_with_rubber_sole.jpg/1200px-Shoe-Blucher-Black_with_rubber_sole.jpg"
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="ClassImage" src="https://www.bing.com/th?id=OIP.IeoYLek51JlXIt92tyhXvQHaFF&pid=Api&rs=1" width="100px" height="100px"/>
<select id="Class" name="Class" onchange="CharacterClass(this)">
        <option value="Hat">Hat</option>
        <option value="Shoe">Shoe</option>
</select>
```